# CSS3 not working in IE on my site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a real hard time developing for Internet Explorer.

Below is a snapshot of a project as it appears in IE9 and below that in Google Chrome it looks the same in Firefox as well.

Some of the things not working correctly in IE9 on this page...

- The navigation bar, the links are stuck at the top in IE instead of vertically centered
- The navigation bar does not have the box shadow applied in IE
- The sidebar and content boxes do not have either the shadow or beveled corners in IE
- The Tag boxes do not have the round edges in IE
- In the content section, notice the 2 tags "CSS" and "FONTS" on the right side of page are pushed down, in the Chrome version they are aligned.

The project is not online so I can't show it but I have put the header section into a JSSFiddle page here http://jsfiddle.net/kenLs/3/embedded/result/ you can see that this JSFiddle of the header DOES work correctly in IE9.

That really has me confused, it works on JSFiddle but not on my site.  I have looked at everything I can think of to make it work correctly.  I even added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to my header.  I had some HTLM5 elements on my page but I replaced all them with regular div's just to test with IE, nothing I do seems to change any of these problems.

**IE9 snapshot**
[image: IE 9]

**Chrome snapshot**
[image: chrome]

---

I know this is hard to debug since the project is not online but if you have any ideas why this may be happening I would really love to know.

---

**UPDATE**

I just realized that on that JSFiddle, if I turn off Compatibility view then even the header will look like the one in my image

I also added another simple JSFiddle test that just has the code for my tags, even this little code does not work correctly in IE, I have to hit the compatibility mode for it to work otherwise the corners are square http://jsfiddle.net/j9Qe3/1/

Comment: You should be using `box-shadow`, not `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`, which are very old and deprecated. This will also make it work on IE9.

Comment: I have all 3, are you saying the other 2 will make it not work with IE?

Comment: He's saying that you don't need to use the other two anymore. If you don't need to support older versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox, you can get rid of them to shave some bytes as well as keep your stylesheet clean. But if you do need to support them, keep them.

Comment: @BoltClock good to know I thought they were required for other browsers

Comment: @minitech I added a new simple test of JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j9Qe3/1/ it shows square corners in IE9, it shows rounds corners if I hit Compatibility mode though

Comment: @minitech: as far as Safari goes, `box-shadow` is only supported without the `-webkit-` prefix in version 5.1, i.e. the most recent version.

Comment: I can't believe we all forgot the obligatory "IE Sucks" comment.

Comment: @jasondavis: Works for me on IE9.

Comment: are you sure your doctype is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in jsfiddle but not on your site, I wonder if you are using a doctype or if there is anything placed before the doctype which would put IE into quirks mode.

Comment: After I posted, I realized that even in JSFiddle if I hit the compatibility mode button then it breaks as well